# TextBlock of the cell is selected on single click edit in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Functionalities I want in my `DataGrid`

1) Column Header should be center aligned.

2) Cell value should be left aligned.

3) Single click edit on a cell.

For the header to be center aligned, I set the HeaderStyle for the column. 
I had to set the cell content to be left aligned explicitly because of this.

I handle the single click edit by using the following code -

```
 <DataGrid SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader">
   <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
      </DataGrid.Resources>
      <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Expressions" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>

                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>


 private void DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
     DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
     if (!cell.IsFocused)
     {
        cell.Focus();
     }
     if (cell != null && !cell.IsEditing && !cell.IsReadOnly)
     {

        DataGrid dataGrid = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(cell);
        if (dataGrid != null)
        {
           if (dataGrid.SelectionUnit != DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow)
           {
              if (!cell.IsSelected)
                 cell.IsSelected = true;
           }
           else
           {
              DataGridRow row = FindVisualParent<DataGridRow>(cell);
              if (row != null && !row.IsSelected)
              {
                 row.IsSelected = true;
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

When I click on the cell, it looks like this - 
[image: Single click edit]

I think the TextBlock is selected and the editing element TextBox is in edit mode. How do I remove the blue colour around the text?

Comment: Is it the last issue you want to focus on or all? I recommend an edit to the question to not ask multiple questions, but focus on one issue. That will improve the chances of getting an answer. Use other questions for other issues which are related.

Comment: Yes. My focus is on the last issue. Will edit my question. Thanks for the suggestion.